# Change a variable in a javascript function with userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to get the IKEA kitchen planner to work on Firefox in Linux. The OS/Browser detection function uses a bunch of if/else statements to determine what platform the user is on, and I believe I can make it work by changing the value of a variable to "true" or by removing all lines that set it to "false".

I've learned a lot about userscripts and greasemonkey since I started this and here's what I've tried so far:

- [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute) event handler
- [hijacking scripts guide](http://userscripts-mirror.org/guides/471) (this seemed promising)
- other stuff that became irrelevant when I learned more about js
- changing the user agent (which is how I worked out the platform detection is clever)

It doesn't work in a virtual machine because hardware acceleration doesn't seem to work well. When that's turned off it works, but the software 3d implementation is so slow that it is unusable, hence trying to get it to work on Linux natively.

For those who would like to try it google "ikea kitchen planner" and follow the links (I can't post any more).

The function that determines whether you get the application or the "use a different OS/browser" page is in a file called UI_All.js (there are some numbers in there too but they may possibly vary).

Comment: I would suggest to copy the `UI_All.js` modify it and use the `beforescriptexecute` (or another method from the hijacking scripts guide) to inject your own version. -- assuming you tried that, what didn't work?

Comment: Use a plugin called Mason and fake your UserAgent. There are many others plugins that do the same.

Comment: @jandob the htm (not html) page that loads that script seems to only load a function from that js file, and it does all this in one go. There are no explicit <script> tags that load the UI_All.js, it's all one command.

Comment: @w35l3y I used "User Agent Switcher" by Chris Pederick, that didn't work. i'll have a look at Mason.